# How do I call this function to do a string lookup and then print the result to the screen?

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

The function is listed below. I want to know how write the user code to do a string look up and print the string to the screen.

```
list_t *lookup_string(hash_table *hashtable, char *str) {

    list_t *list;
    unsigned int hashval = hash(hashtable, str);

    // go to the correct list based on the hash value and see if str is in the list. If it is, return
    // a pointer to the list element. If it isn't, the item isn't in the table, so return NULL.

    for (list = hashtable->table[hashval]; list != NULL; list = list->next) {

        if (strcmp(str, list->next) == 0) {

            return list;

        }

        return NULL;
    }
}
```

The user defined data types are listed below.

```
typedef struct _list_t_ {

char *string;
struct _list_t_ *next;

} list_t;

typedef struct _hash_table_t_ {

int size;   //the size of the table
list_t **table;   //the table elements

} hash_table;
```

Comment: Hm... aren't the two snippets identical? Anyway, the question is unclear.

Comment: Even without structure definitions, `strcmp(str, list->next)` is *highly* suspicious.

Comment: ... and should spew a warning or error for incompatible types if `next` is indeed `list_t*` as suspected.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Well *technically* you can convert any pointer to a pointer of character type, so it wouldn't necessarily produce an error, but a warning *would* be nice.

Comment: @EOF the actual *problem* from the OP would be even nicer.

Comment: Post definition of `list_t`.

Comment: You said the data types are listed below, but you forgot to list them.

Comment: My apologies. I have added the data types via an edit.

Comment: You are right EOF. It was supposed to be strcmp(str, list->string).

Comment: A hash table is usually used to map names to values. Your hash table has names, but no values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't compare the string with `list->next`, you should compare it with the key of the hash table entry.

```
for (list = hashtable->table[hashval]; list != NULL; list = list->next) {
    if (strcmp(str, list->string) == 0) {
        return list;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You are right Barmar. Your suggestion solved the problem.